# CrudRepository query multiple one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud-repository

I want to delete an entry from the database using the crudRepository. I have a Timecard entity with a one-to-many relationship with the Task entity, and the Task has a one-to-many relationship with Project. I want to delete an element of the database based on taskId and projectId.

Here are the definitions of the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timecards")
public class TimeCard{

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "timecard_id", nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "timecardSequence", sequenceName = "timecardIdSequence", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "timecardSequence")
    @Id
    private Long timeCardId;

    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id") 
    private Task task;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task{

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "taskSequence", sequenceName = "taskIdSequence", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "taskSequence")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "task_id", nullable = false)
    private int taskId;

    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")
    private Project project;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project implements Serializable {
   
    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
    @Id
    private Long projectId;
```

```
@Repository
public interface TimeCardRepository extends CrudRepository<TimeCard, String>{
 public void deleteTimeCardByTaskTaskIdAndTaskProjectProjectId(int taskId, Long projectId);
}
```

deleteTimeCardByTaskTaskIdAndTaskProjectProjectId is my property expressions but unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.spring.data.deployment.UnableToParseMethodException: Entity com.timecardservice.timecard.TimeCard does not contain a field named: TaskProject_ProjectId. Offending method is deleteTimeCardByTaskTaskIdAndTaskProjectProjectId
```

I checked https://evonsdesigns.medium.com/spring-jpa-one-to-many-query-examples-281078bc457b for transversal point but I get the same error message.

What is the proper way to do this query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a _ to access properties of joined tables/enities.

So it should be

```
public void deleteTimeCardByTask_TaskIdAndTask_Project_ProjectId(int taskId, Long projectId);
```

You can also check the logged sql statement with

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: I tried previously the usage of "_" as suggested in https://evonsdesigns.medium.com/spring-jpa-one-to-many-query-examples-281078bc457b but it didn't work. Unfortunately, your suggestion is not working as well.

Comment: Yes. If I do deleteTimeCardByTask_TaskIdAndTask_Project(int taskId, Long projectId) or deleteTimeCardByTaskTaskIdAndTaskProject(int taskId, Long projectId) it works fine... But somehow the crudRepository is not able to access second level joined tables properties...

Comment: You should check your Join's (@ManyToMany annotations) it is working in an example project without errors. With `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` i can see a select first with the correct join of the three tables.

Why Task has id and taskId? 

Can you please create a method to read a TimeCard by taskId and ProjectId?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers. taskId is a value that I retrieve from a file that is between 1 to 5 basically. I'll try to create the methods you ask me, see if it works.

Comment: This is what I see with quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true when getting timecards based on a taskId ```select
        timecard0_.timecard_id as timecard1_3_,
        timecard0_.task_id as task_id5_3_ 
    from
        timecards timecard0_ cross 
    join
        tasks task1_ 
    where
        timecard0_.task_id=task1_.id 
        and task1_.task_id=? limit ?``` I didn't manage to do it for projectId since I get the same error as before.

Comment: @Babas can you please change 
`@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")`
To `@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")` or `@JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "projectId")`

I think the join/relation between task and project is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If the JPA way is not sufficient, you can always use a NativeQuery/JPQLQuery to do the work:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM TimeCard tc WHERE tc.task.taskId = :taskId and tc.task.project.projectId = :projectId")
List<Long> deleteByIds(@Param("taskId") Long taskId, @Param("projectId") Long projectId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the query explicit:

```
@Repository
public interface TimeCardRepository extends CrudRepository<TimeCard, String>{

  @Modifying 
  @Query(value = "DELETE FROM tc timeCard WHERE tc IN ( "
                 + "SELECT timeCard FROM timeCard  "
                 + " JOIN timeCard.task task "
                 + " JOIN taks.project project "
                 + " WHERE task.id = :taskId AND project.id= :projectId)") 
 public void deleteTimeCardByTaskTaskIdAndTaskProjectProjectId(int taskId, Long projectId);
}
```